# Adding attributes for fields using ejs view helpers

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using ejs template rendering

```
<%- input_field_tag('inputFld', 5) %>
```

This code generates input field as

```
<input id="inputFld" value="" type="5" name="inputFld">
```

Now I want `id` and `name` attribute different
ie. `id="inputFldID"` and `name="inputFldName"` also I want to add `class` attribute.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `text_field_tag`, because `type="5"` doesn't make much sense.

You can pass object as third argument to `text_field_tag` with attributes you want to set.

```
<%- text_field_tag('inputFld', '5', {id: 'inputFldId', Class: 'some_class'}) %>
```